# How to find and summarize specific strings in a pandas dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe that is like the following:

| Well ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 to 2 Gra | 4 to 5 Blu Gra | 5 to 7 Red |  | NaN |
| 101 | 1 to 3 Blu | 3 to 6 Gra | Nan |  | NaN |

What I'm trying to do is add two columns at the end of the dataframe, the first with all the records that contain the string Gra, the second with the last record. So Well 101 would get a new column Gra, which would contain [3 to 6 Gra] and a new column Last Record that would contain [3 to 6 Gra].

I've tried using:

```
for key, value in df_gravel.iteritems():
if value.astype(str).str.contains(search_word, case=False).any():
    print(value)
```

But I just get the whole column. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

The expected table after this would be:
[image: Expected Result]

Comment: An example of the expected output could be helpful here. It's a little unclear.

Comment: Hopefully the updated table helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First stack the columns of interest. Then filter the rows containing `Gra` then groupby and aggregate to list

```
s = df.iloc[:, 1:].stack()

df['Gra']  = s[s.str.contains('Gra')].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
df['Last'] = s.groupby(level=0).agg('last')
```

---

```
   Well ID           1               2           3   4   5                           Gra        Last
0      100  1 to 2 Gra  4 to 5 Blu Gra  5 to 7 Red NaN NaN  [1 to 2 Gra, 4 to 5 Blu Gra]  5 to 7 Red
1      101  1 to 3 Blu      3 to 6 Gra         NaN NaN NaN                  [3 to 6 Gra]  3 to 6 Gra
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I had to modify it slightly to df['Gra']  = s[s.str.astype(str).contains('Gra')].groupby(level=0).agg(list) to get around the NaN's.